# How to add QLineEdit to QMessageBox PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyqt5, qlineedit, qmessagebox

I want a copyable text on my QMessageBox so I thought I can put a QLineEdit on QMessageBox then set the text of QLineEdit whatever I want, so user can choose the text and copy it.

But I couldn't success. Is there a way to add QLineEdit to QMessageBox or make a copyable text on QMessageBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by playing with `QMessageBox.informativeText()`, `QMessageBox.detailedText()` and `QMessageBox.textInteractionFlags()` i found the following:

`QMessageBox.informativeText()` and `QMessageBox.detailedText()` are always selectable, even if  `QmessageBox.textInteractionFlags()` are set to `QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction`. `QMessageBox.detailedText()` is shown in a textedit. `QMessageBox.setTextInteractionFlags()` only acts on `QmessageBox.text()`. The use of these kinds of text is descripted in [documentation of QMessageBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#details). By flags you can set the text editable and/or selectable, see [enum TextInteractionFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextInteractionFlag-enum).

Here an working example with selectable text in `QmessageBox.detailedText()`:

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self): 
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self) 
        self.setGeometry(400,50,200,200)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('show messagebox', self)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(25, 90, 150, 25)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

    def onClick(self):
        msgbox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msgbox.setText('to select click "show details"')
        msgbox.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction) # (QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        msgbox.setDetailedText('line 1\nline 2\nline 3')
        msgbox.exec()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MyWidget()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If I copy paste your codes into an empty script that works, but when I tried to set it in my main script I get this error: `msgbox.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setTextInteractionFlags'` Class is starting with this: `class Example(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()`

Comment: I worked on it and fixed. I just put the text with setText method. Thank you for your answer, I didn't know there is a method like that setTtextInteraction() etc. If you can give more info about them in your answer it'll be good for future visiters.